# Time Complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: search, time, binary, big-o, time-complexity

Need help figuring out the time complexity of this algorithm using Big-O notation. Cheers.

```
int binarySearch(int[] array, int key) {
    int lo = 0, mid, hi = array.length-1;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        mid = (lo + hi)/2;
        if (key < array[mid])
            hi = mid - 1;
        else if (array[mid] < key)
            lo = mid + 1;
        else return mid; // success
    }
    return -1; // failure
}
```

Comment: Does not demonstrate any effort at attempting a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you double the number of elements in the array, then the expected number of steps goes up by 1. Therefore it's O(log(N)); where log is base 2.

Comment: Hey cheers I know its O(log(n)... I want to know why it is...

Comment: @subzerok; you mean my answer is not sufficient to explain?

Answer (score -1):

If you do not find what you search, each time the range where you do you search becomes two times smaller. For example, 64 -> 32 -> 16 etc. That is, you will need to iterate lb(n) at most. Therefore, the running time is O(lb(n)), where lb(n) is logarithm of base 2 of n.

Comment: Hey cheers I know its O(log(n)... I want to know why it is...

Comment: not really an explanation :(